# Number of cells in array in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
fid=fopen('transform.txt');
alltext = textscan(fid, '%s');

d = size(alltext)

for k=1:1
    line = alltext{1}{k}
end
```

I am using `size()` function to get the number of cells but it is not giving me my desired Answer....I want the number of cells in array variable named `alltext`

Transform.txt File

mecca06.pgm
2
0.707 -0.1414 0 0.707 1.2726 0 0 0 1
mecca06.pgm
c

Comment: Can you give an example alltext, just print it out and show it here?

Comment: "Transform.txt" File added in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If textscan finds strings it returns a cell array of one or multiple cell arrays. The number of specifiers (in your case %s) you search for defines the number of nested cell arrays it returns. 
Most primitive solution for your case, where you only search for %s would be:

```
 d = size(alltext{1});
```